# Variables with For loop in bash ${var_$i}

Tags: bash

I am calling the defined variables inside a loop and it shows me "bad substitution" error. I know I am doing something wrong in my script or this is not the right of doing it. But in theory, I should be able to call those variables in the for loop so that, my script can execute the number of times these variables have been defined.

```
#!/bin/bash

export CONFIG_FILE=$1

. $CONFIG_FILE

for ((  i = 1 ;  i <= $Deploys;  i++  ))
do
        echo ${Source_Path_$i}
        echo ${Dest_Server_$i}
        echo ${Dest_Path_$i}
done
```

Content of CONFIG_FILE

```
export Deploys=2

export Source_Path_1=./Source1
export Dest_Server_1=Server1
export Dest_Path_1=/Destination1


export Source_Path_2=./Source2
export Dest_Server_2=Server2
export Dest_Path_2=/Destination2
```

This is the error I get when I execute the bash script

```
line 9: ${Source_Path_$i}: bad substitution
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you 'source' your config file you no longer need to use export, and it's also better to just use arrays:

```
Deploys=2

Source_Path[1]=./Source1
Dest_Server[1]=Server1
Dest_Path[1]=/Destination1

Source_Path[2]=./Source2
Dest_Server[2]=Server2
Dest_Path[2]=/Destination2
```

And have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG_FILE=$1

. "$CONFIG_FILE"

for (( i = 1; i <= Deploys; i++ ))
do
    echo "${Source_Path[i]}"
    echo "${Dest_Server[i]}"
    echo "${Dest_Path[i]}"
done
```

You could try a safe eval too besides variable indirection in which an example was already provided, but it's not really a commendable solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG_FILE=$1

. "$CONFIG_FILE"

for (( i = 1; i <= Deploys; i++ ))
do
    eval "echo \"\${Source_Path_$i}\""
    eval "echo \"\${Dest_Server_$i}\""
    eval "echo \"\${Dest_Path_$i}\""
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use variable indirection with `${!var}` to solve the problem reliably. However, it is a bit more verbose:

```
for (( i = 1 ;  i <= $Deploys;  i++ )); do
    source="Source_Path_$i"
    echo "${!source}"
    server="Dest_Server_$i"
    echo "${!server}"
    path="Dest_Path_$i"
    echo "${!path}"
done
```